# Location Based activity, opening intent according to the distance

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

I am developing an app who makes basically the following things: when the GPS is enabled it takes the current position and calculates the distance between the location took from the location manager and a fixed position, then when the distance is lower than a value, for example 10 meters,  the app automatically open another `Activity` containing the informations about the location reached, the problem is that when the user is visualizing the info page he remains in the range and the previous activity continues opening the same activity with informations, how can i prevent this problem? I need to stop the method  that open the new `Intent` when the info are visualized and then restart when the user is back in the distance calculation `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called proximity alerts. May be you have implemented this on your own and which is not working properly. Look into the implementation of [Proximity Alerts](https://github.com/gauntface/Android-Proximity-Alerts-Example). Moreover this will have two notifications when user enters into range and when exits from the range.

Comment: thanks, i will check and see how to correct my version!

Comment: I read it but it's not perfectly fitting what i need, i have this issue to stop the thread who checks the distance when i am into another activity and the one with the map is on pause, i just need to synchronize that function when i am not in the map page